# How to skip variables when selecting into (MySQL stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Take the following MySQL query written into a stored procedure:

```
SELECT @one := 1, @two := 2, (@one + @two) AS three INTO p_one, p_two, p_three;
```

Is there any way to skip INTO variables, say I don't need `p_one` and `p_two`? I am looking for something like

```
SELECT @one := 1, @two := 2, (@one + @two) AS three INTO p_three;
```

but I know this syntax is not right.

The only way I found right now is to wrap this query into yet another *superquery* and `SELECT` only the appropriate subquery fields.

Comment: Curiosity and thus prettier code.

Comment: No, coz the scope of the allias name will remain till the query in the procedure. U will have to explicitly declare that